# What is the best way to show an isomorphism for small groups?

Tags: group-theory

Suppose I want to show two groups are isomorphic to each other and the two groups have a small size, $4$ for example.

Would it be okay to simply show were each of the four elements get mapped to in the other group and then show the composition tables for each group and show that they are consistent with the defined map, or is that considered bad form?

It seems for small elements this is more efficient (and more obvious to me at least) what is going on rather than explicitly proving the required properties for a isomorphism. Of course when it is not feasible to show the composition tables and the map explicitly it will be necessary to show the isomorphism differently.

For example:

Say we have a group $G$ that is isomorphic to $V_4$ the Klein-$4$ group.

Would it be necessary to show that $\phi (ab)=\phi(a) \phi(b)$ for each $a,b$ or could you just draw the composition tables on both sides and show which element in $V_4$ the ($4$) elements of $G$ are mapped to.

Thanks!

Comment: The common way is to construct a bijective homomorphism.

Comment: Single out the generators in a group, and work with their orders.  E.g., the Klein group has 2 generators, each of order 2.  Meanwhile, the cyclic group of size 4 has 1 generator of order 4.  Hence, the two groups fail to be isomorphic.

Comment: Such a proof  though technically correct would be considered an engineering hack than a mathematical approach.  And it is not a compliment.

Comment: Yes. That's brief, to the point, and lets you move on to something more interesting. Those with doubts can look at the multiplication tables and check that all's well. Indeed, it's what I'd prefer. Then again, if you look at the answers I post, you'll see that I like to answer questions about very general spaces by looking at examples like "a discrete space with two elements", or answer questions about general matrices with 1 x 1 examples. They get to the heart of things quickly, and separate the idea from the notation and the mathematical showmanship.

Answer (score 2):

That is completely fine for small groups.  One benefit is that the composition tables then give the full isomorphism, rather than being explained indirectly.